# How do I make a link take entire available height using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how do I make my `<a>` tags in my Navbar take the full available height from it´s parent instead of just the space required by the content?

Currently, the hover effect only triggers when you mouseover the TEXT, because that's all the space that the content is taking. I want the entire available height to be clickable when hovered.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --clr-800: #0d0d0d;
  --clr-600: #122459;
  --clr-400: #3565f2;
  --clr-200: #3d79f2;
  --clr-100: #f2f2f2;

  --font-primary: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  --font-secondary: "Bebas Neue", cursive;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--font-primary);
  background: var(--clr-100);
  color: var(--clr-800);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-secondary);
}

header {
  background-color: var(--clr-800);
  color: var(--clr-100);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem var(--clr-800);
  height: 40vh;

}

header > h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 4rem;
}

nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 4rem 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav > ul > li {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  color: var(--clr-100);
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: var(--clr-800);
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Montserrat:wght@300;500;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure should work nicely for you. I recommend getting good at using your browser dev tools. If you inspect your elements you will notice that `nav` and `ul` need to have `height: 100%;` to fill the available `header` height.

Then, you need to set `min-height: 100%;` on `a` and use `flex` with `align-items: center;` to center them once again. I adjusted the spacing by adding horizontal `padding` and `margin` on the `a` so it doesn't affect the clicking area.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --clr-800: #0d0d0d;
  --clr-600: #122459;
  --clr-400: #3565f2;
  --clr-200: #3d79f2;
  --clr-100: #f2f2f2;
  --font-primary: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  --font-secondary: "Bebas Neue", cursive;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--font-primary);
  background: var(--clr-100);
  color: var(--clr-800);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-secondary);
}

header {
  background-color: var(--clr-800);
  color: var(--clr-100);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem var(--clr-800);
  height: 40vh;
}

header>h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 4rem;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  color: var(--clr-100);
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: var(--clr-800);
  background-color: red;
}

a {
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin: 0 .5em;
}

nav,
ul {
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Montserrat:wght@300;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did try setting `nav` and `ul` to `height: 100%;` but it didn't cross my mind that I had to set the `<a>` to `min-height: 100%;`

Comment: I use `min-height` to ensure it never shrinks below `100%`. However, the largest factor is the `flex` on `a`. As long as you have the `flex`, `height` will work just as well.

Comment: I just noticed that if I omit the `height` attribute in the `<header>` it will stop working. Just out curiosity, is there a way to not have a specific height set ( so it just uses whatever the current content that is inside needs ).

Comment: @MarcosGruah the `h1` has a significantly larger `font-size` than your `li`. This is causing the extra space you see. You need to either set `font-size: inherit` on `h1` or use a `height` on the `header` so it knows to take up all available space.